# error: unable to parse "'{\"spec\":": yaml: found unexpected end of stream while patching the new storage request in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pvc

I am using below command to patch new storage to volumeclaimtemplate:

```
 minikube kubectl -- --namespace default patch pvc elasticsearch-data-elasticsearch-data-0 --patch '{\"spec\": {\"volumeClaimTemplate\": {\"requests\": {\"storage\": \"2Gi\"}}}}'
```

But, I am getting the below error:

```
error: unable to parse "'{\"spec\":": YAML: found unexpected end of stream.
```

Should I use another escape character instead of ""?
Please Help.

Comment: The only way to make patching work was to use a json string, like this:


minikube kubectl -- --namespace default patch pvc elasticsearch-data-elasticsearch-data-0 --patch “{\"spec\": {\"volumeClaimTemplate\": {\"requests\": {\"storage\": \"2Gi\"}}}}”

#Use double quotes instead of single quotes for the patch string.

[Refer this doc for more information](https://github.com/TsuyoshiUshio/KubernetesTask/issues/36)

Comment: Does this help you in resolving your query and let us know where you struck?

Answer (score 5):

Replacing single quote and escaping double quotes worked for me.

Result is then :

```
--patch "{\"spec\": {\"volumeClaimTemplate\": {\"requests\": {\"storage\": \"2Gi\"}}}}"
```